# Reaflow - Panning issue

Tags: reactjs

I am using reaflow to create flowcharts but I am facing some issue with panning. the library contains an attribute which enables panning but their panning is not what I thought it to be. For me , panning is something with which I can move the flowchart by clicking somewhere on the canvas and moving the cursor but I am not able to do that.

To overcome this I started using [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinch) library but that is not working for me. basically It is getting out of the viewport.

Please refer my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Canvas } from 'reaflow';
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from 'react-zoom-pan-pinch'

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App' style={{ height: 400, width: 700, position: 'relative', background: 'white' }}>
      <div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
        <TransformWrapper>
          <TransformComponent>
            <Canvas
              nodes={[
                {
                  id: '1',
                  text: '1'
                },
                {
                  id: '2',
                  text: '2'
                },
                {
                  id: '3',
                  text: '3'
                },
                {
                  id: '4',
                  text: '4'
                }
              ]}
              edges={[
                {
                  id: '1-2',
                  from: '1',
                  to: '2'
                },
                {
                  id: '1-3',
                  from: '1',
                  to: '3'
                },
                {
                  id: '2-3',
                  from: '2',
                  to: '3'
                },
                {
                  id: '3-4',
                  from: '3',
                  to: '4'
                }
              ]}
            />
          </TransformComponent>
        </TransformWrapper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```